# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/app/Fragment;.getContext()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have problem with my app under API 21, i have this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Landroid/app/Fragment;.getContext()

Anyone can help me?

Comment: This is at build time or running time? In which part of the code is this happening?

Comment: could you elaborate more with the code you used?

Comment: For similar error but regarding location ended up that API Level 26 or above is needed. It may be this same issue

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Activity` property of the `Fragment` instead of `Context`.

Answer (score -2):

In the xamarin android there is no `getContext` method. You should use `Context` instead.

Comment: This is generated at runtime when you use Context. Context calls getContext in  java and the java is complaining that getContext doesn't exist.